# Refreshing the session in Amplify using currentAuthenticatedUser()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-serverless, refresh-token

I am currently refreshing the id token with Amplify in my serverless backend.

What I do is I send the `refreshToken` request to backend, and use `cognitoUser.refreshSession` to get the new token.

Here is my backend code:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { awsconfig } from '../aws-exports';

class CognitoService {
  constructor() {
    Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
    this.auth = Amplify.Auth;
  }

  async refreshToken() {
    try {
      const cognitoUser = await this.auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      const cognitoSession = await this.getCognitoSession(cognitoUser);
      const refreshedSessionToken = await this.refreshSession(cognitoUser, cognitoSession);
      return refreshedSessionToken;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error('Fail to refresh token');
    }
  }

  getToken(userSession) {
    return {
      accessToken: userSession.idToken.jwtToken,
      refreshToken: userSession.refreshToken.token,
      expire: userSession.idToken.payload.exp
    };
  }

  getCognitoSession(cognitoUser) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cognitoUser.getSession((err, result) => {
        if (err || !result) {
          reject(new Error('Failure getting Cognito session: ' + err));
          return
        }

        console.debug('Successfully got session: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        resolve(result);
      })
    })
  }

  refreshSession(cognitoUser, cognitoSession) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cognitoUser.refreshSession(cognitoSession.getRefreshToken(), (err, session) => {
        if (err || !session) {
          reject(new Error('Failure refresh Cognito session: ' + err));
          return
        }

        resolve(this.getToken(session));
      })
    })
  }
}

export { CognitoService };
```

Actually it works well in most of the time. The token is updated in frontend every single successful fetch.
However after few times it will be failed.

[Request fail after few successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgloX.png)

The refresh token is valid for 30days and the idtoken is valid for 1hour.

The error message I got:

`INFO The user is not authenticated`

`ERROR Error: Fail to refresh token at cognitoService_CognitoService.refreshToken`

Any idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this?